# Codeigniter 4 Autogenerated File In System Folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-4

I'm curious about the auto generated file in System folder. It's always generated automatically when I reload my web browser and if I open one of that file, that file contains HTML code similar like what I wrote in view file.
Below is the image of the autogenerated files.

[image]

Could anyone give me an explaination about this ? Please, help.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the CodeIgniter forums specifically.